# how to find the value which is common in a column for all the values in other column?

Tags: oracle

If i'm having a table like this.

```
col1    col2   col3
1       2       3
1       3       2
1       2       1
1       2       2
1       2       3
```

I want only the col2 values which appears for all three values(1,2,3) in col3

```
col2
2
```

How to get result like this guys?

Comment: self join @davegreen 100

Comment: Like select a.col2 from table a,table b where a.col3<>b.col3 and a.col2=b.col2

Comment: Is it guaranteed that 1, 2 and 3 are the only possible values in col3?

Comment: yes @mureinik the values may get repeated in that column

Answer (score 3):

```
select col2
from your_table
group by col2
having count(distinct col3) = (select count(distinct col3) from your_table)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that 1, 2 and 3 are the only acceptable values for col3 (and that the column is not null), then you could do it like this:

```
with sample_data as (select 1 col1, 2 col2, 3 col3 from dual union all
                     select 1 col1, 3 col2, 2 col3 from dual union all
                     select 1 col1, 2 col2, 1 col3 from dual union all
                     select 1 col1, 2 col2, 2 col3 from dual union all
                     select 1 col1, 2 col2, 3 col3 from dual),
             res as (select col1,
                            col2,
                            col3,
                            count(distinct col3) over (partition by col1, col2) cnt_distinct_col3
                     from   sample_data)
select col1,
       col2,
       col3
from   res
where  cnt_distinct_col3 = 3;

      COL1       COL2       COL3
---------- ---------- ----------
         1          2          1
         1          2          2
         1          2          3
         1          2          3
```

I wasn't sure from your sample_data if you were just going from col2, or whether it was col1 + col2; eg, if the sample data was:

```
      COL1       COL2       COL3
---------- ---------- ----------
         1          2          3
         1          3          2
         1          2          1
         1          2          2
         1          2          3
         2          3          1
         2          3          3
```

Would you expect to see col2 = 2 and col2 = 3 rows returned, or would you only expect to see (col1, col2) = (1, 2) rows returned?

I have assumed the latter, but if it's the former, it's just a case of taking col1 out of the partition clause in the analytic function. And then, of course, changing the select to "select distinct col2".

---

So, depending on how you want the answers displayed, I think my query works for the situations where you want to show col1 in the results (ie. unfiltered) and when you want to filter by a specific col1 value, e.g;

```
with sample_data as (select 1 col1, 2 col2, 3 col3 from dual union all
                     select 1 col1, 3 col2, 2 col3 from dual union all
                     select 1 col1, 2 col2, 1 col3 from dual union all
                     select 1 col1, 2 col2, 2 col3 from dual union all
                     select 1 col1, 2 col2, 3 col3 from dual union all
                     select 2 col1, 3 col2, 1 col3 from dual union all
                     select 2 col1, 3 col2, 2 col3 from dual union all
                     select 2 col1, 3 col2, 3 col3 from dual union all
                     select 2 col1, 2 col2, 1 col3 from dual union all
                     select 3 col1, 1 col2, 2 col3 from dual union all
                     select 3 col1, 1 col2, 3 col3 from dual),
             res as (select col1,
                            col2,
                            col3,
                            count(distinct col3) over (partition by col1, col2) cnt_distinct_col3
                     from   sample_data)
select distinct col1,
                col2
from   res
where  cnt_distinct_col3 = 3;

      COL1       COL2
---------- ----------
         2          3
         1          2

with sample_data as (select 1 col1, 2 col2, 3 col3 from dual union all
                     select 1 col1, 3 col2, 2 col3 from dual union all
                     select 1 col1, 2 col2, 1 col3 from dual union all
                     select 1 col1, 2 col2, 2 col3 from dual union all
                     select 1 col1, 2 col2, 3 col3 from dual union all
                     select 2 col1, 3 col2, 1 col3 from dual union all
                     select 2 col1, 3 col2, 2 col3 from dual union all
                     select 2 col1, 3 col2, 3 col3 from dual union all
                     select 2 col1, 2 col2, 1 col3 from dual union all
                     select 3 col1, 1 col2, 2 col3 from dual union all
                     select 3 col1, 1 col2, 3 col3 from dual),
             res as (select col1,
                            col2,
                            col3,
                            count(distinct col3) over (partition by col1, col2) cnt_distinct_col3
                     from   sample_data)
select distinct col2
from   res
where  cnt_distinct_col3 = 3
and    col1 = 1;

      COL2
----------
         2
```

---

Ok, I think this is what you're after:

```
with sample_data as (select 1 col1, 2 col2, 3 col3 from dual union all
                     select 1 col1, 3 col2, 2 col3 from dual union all
                     select 1 col1, 2 col2, 1 col3 from dual union all
                     select 1 col1, 2 col2, 2 col3 from dual union all
                     select 1 col1, 2 col2, 3 col3 from dual union all
                     select 2 col1, 3 col2, 1 col3 from dual union all
                     select 2 col1, 3 col2, 2 col3 from dual union all
                     select 2 col1, 3 col2, 3 col3 from dual union all
                     select 2 col1, 2 col2, 1 col3 from dual union all
                     select 3 col1, 1 col2, 2 col3 from dual union all
                     select 3 col1, 1 col2, 3 col3 from dual),
             res as (select col1,
                            col2,
                            col3,
                            count(distinct col3) over (partition by col1, col2) cnt_distinct_col3_per_col1col2,
                            count(distinct col3) over (partition by col1) cnt_distinct_col3_per_col1
                     from   sample_data)
select distinct col2
from   res
where  cnt_distinct_col3_per_col1col2 = cnt_distinct_col3_per_col1
and    col1 = 1;

      COL2
----------
         2
```

The way this works is:

1. find the number of distinct col3 values for each col1 value. (So in the example above, for col1 = 1, there are 3 different col3 values.)
2. find the number of distinct col3 values for each (col1, col2) pairing. (So in the example above, for (col1, col2) = (1, 2) there are 3 different col3 values, and for (col1, col2) = (1, 3) there is only 1)
3. select the rows where these two numbers match. (So from the above example, only (col1, col2) = (1, 2) has the same number of distinct values (3) as col1 = 1 does (3).

Comment: I want to include a condition like for col1=1 i have to find the records(c02) which is common in third column(col3).

Comment: why're you giving that value as 3 for cnt_distinct_col=3?

Comment: Because you said col3 only held the values 1, 2 and 3. So if there are 3 distinct values, then they must be 1, 2 and 3.

Comment: Thanks for the code.But I'm having a doubt how does the partition by statement works for this scenario?

Comment: But the real scenario is having lot of values in col3 since i'm filtering that with col1=1 i didn't mention about that.Does it involve any impact on the result? @Boneist

Comment: Well, yes. I'm assuming that you might want to apply the same logic for col1 = 2. Is that not the case? Also, when looking at the vals in col3, are you wanting to know which col2 val has all of the different vals that col3 has got that particular col1? I.e. if col1 = 1 had vals [1, 2, 3, 5] in col3, you'd be looking for the col2 vals that had 1, 2, 3 and 5?

Comment: yes,for example col1 has values like 1,2,3,etc i want to find whether the values in col2 appears for all values in col3 corresponding to col1=1

Comment: I want only for col1=1 not for any other values.Consider for only one value in col1

Comment: so whether it will work  if i have more than 5 values in col3 or not?

Comment: Yes. It would be extremely easy for you to update the input data in the query I provided to test this (you'd just need to add in more selects into the sample_data subquery, with the corresponding values that you wanted to test for) and try it out yourself.